# Viewing files behind splash page on server

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, webserver

I've got a web server (FTP) hosting my website. Now, I have put a splash page saying "WEBSITE COMING SOON" in an attempt to hide the site I'm developing behind it.

So my splash page is `splash.html` and I have a few files behind it such as `index.php`, `about.php` and `contact.php`

When I type `http://www.mysite/index.php` it just re-routes to the `sample.html`

Could anyone tell me how I can view my files in the browser after making code modifications to them in my text editor.

Please note - client's infrastructure means I have to develop on live, hidden site and my `.htaccess` file contains `DirectoryIndex sample.html`.

Comment: Place them in a different folder?

Comment: Test them on a local webserver?

Comment: For starters, can you share the contents of index.php and .htaccess?